# When observers moving along different geodesics meet locally, can they detect one another's acceleration?

Tags: general-relativity, classical-mechanics, gravity, geodesics, equivalence-principle

Consider two free-falling observers in the Earth's gravitational field, A and B, who meet at point C, where A orbits the Earth at a constant radius from the Earth's center, and B falls towards the Earth's center along a constant radial line: Can either detect the other accelerating locally at C?

As an attempt to answer this myself: it's worth noting that I can detect the acceleration of an object dropped onto the surface of the Earth where I am, and that the Earth is free falling along a geodesic within the solar system. However, I don't think the Earth's surface is a geodesic because I can drill a small hole from the surface towards the Earth's center so that a small mass will accelerate towards the center where, at the center, it will experience a zero acceleration. Hence an observer at the Earth's center can't measure the acceleration of another moving mass there, and on another geodesic.

So I'm inclined to believe that neither A and B can detect one another accelerating at C locally when they meet, and that more generally: observers on different geodesics can't detect one another accelerating wrt one another locally when they meet.

Answer (score 0):

Your assessment is correct.

By the equivalence principle, free fall in a gravitational field is locally equivalent to inertial motion in flat spacetime. So two local observers will only detect straight-line motion.

Of course, the word “local” is doing a lot of heavy lifting in that claim. There is nothing stopping you from detecting the relative acceleration. But the scale at which you can do that defines the scale that is considered “local”.

Comment: One can easily watch the tidal forces on the ISS and they are not just straight line motion. Approaching the ISS with another spacecraft is anything but a "straight" operation. It's actually quite counterintuitive, at least for my limited intuition. Are a few meters to kilometers "local enough" compared to 6500km of orbital radius?

Comment: @FlatterMann if you can detect tidal effects then by definition it is not local. But remember that we are talking about spacetime. The experiments you reference may cover a few meters in space, but they cover billions of meters in time.

Comment: The point is that acceleration is always non-local. It was that already in Newtonian mechanics. To be honest, the physics of a single spacetime point is rather boring. I don't know what a meter of time is, either. I usually measure time in seconds.

Comment: @FlatterMann you can certainly have local acceleration. Just not local tidal effects. Time is commonly measured in distance units in relativity. A meter of time is the time it takes for light to travel 1 m. Roughly 3 ns

Comment: Acceleration is always an effect that requires three different spacetime points to measure. Velocity requires two. Position requires one. That's just the reality of derivatives, I am afraid. I don't measure time by the way light travels. I measure time by the way energy flows. I think that's one of the great problems with Einstein's papers from an educational point of view... he hooked up everything to light, when in reality Lorentz transformations are completely independent of light. Light is merely one of many physical effects that depend on the Lorentz structure of spacetime.

Comment: @FlatterMann while it is true that acceleration requires 3 points, that is not relevant to the discussion of “local”. “Local” does not mean a single event, it just means a small enough region of spacetime that tidal effects are undetectable. So you can indeed have local acceleration. Your comments here are simply not relevant to the topic. If you would like to have a discussion to learn the basics of this material, please go to a discussion forum, like physicsforums.com. This is not the intended use of comments here. I cannot adequately teach these basics in comments here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146620/discussion-between-flattermann-and-dale).